# Linear Regression (OLS): Confidence Intervals are not being calculated accurately using Statsmodel summary_Frame()

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, confidence-interval, standard-error

**Incorrect Confidence Intervals**

I want to calculate the confidence interval of my forecasted values from OLS model in python. I found a function in statmodel that helps you create a dataframe of each forecasted value, se of forecasted value, upper and lower bound values of CI using get_prediction() and then summary_frame().

Unfortunately my upper and lower CI are not matching the results. Please Find attahced screenshot for my code and results [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2erql.png).

Row 1 For Ex: `Forecasted Value - 11.788462, SE - 0.580693, for 95% CI`

```
Lower Bound should be = 11.788462 - (1.96 * 0.580693) = 10.65030372

Upper Bound should be = 11.788462 + (1.96 * 0.580693) = 12.92662028
```

But the results in screenshot are not matching these numbers. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

statsmodels uses the t-distribution by default for inference in linear regression models like OLS.

Because of the very small sample size and low degrees of freedom the critical values of the t-distribution differ from those of the normal distribution in an observable magnitude.

The following replaces the critical value of 1.96 by the critical values from the t-distribution with df=5. The values match those the statsmodels results in the screenshot attached in the question.

```
from scipy import stats

11.788462 + stats.t.ppf(0.025, 5) * 0.580693
Out[12]: 10.295743121550677

11.788462 + stats.t.isf(0.025, 5) * 0.580693
Out[13]: 13.281180878449325
```